# Singleton toolbox vs factory method

Tags: singleton, factory

Apparently, singletons are bad, and a factory method is recommended. I'm wondering if a singleton toolbox is any better than a singleton.

Comment: I'm not sure what to say, or if I should post in Programmers SE instead.

Comment: Who says that singletons are bad? It always depends on how you want to use them. Is there any code that you can show us?

Comment: People say it's bad for unit testing.

Answer (score 0):

In my opinion, It's really weak to think that singletons are bad,factory methods are good.

Each of them has preferences. As consequence, I'm sure that there is misunderstanding here.

I know that wikipedia is not the best source. But check out the definition of them. The range of situations are not the same for these patterns.

> In software engineering, the singleton pattern is a design pattern that restricts the instantiation of a class to one object. This is useful when exactly one object is needed to coordinate actions across the system. The concept is sometimes generalized to systems that operate more efficiently when only one object exists, or that restrict the instantiation to a certain number of objects. The term comes from the mathematical concept of a singleton.
>
> In class-based programming, the factory method pattern is a creational pattern which uses factory methods to deal with the problem of creating objects without specifying the exact class of object that will be created. This is done by creating objects via calling a factory method—either specified in an interface and implemented by child classes, or implemented in a base class and optionally overridden by derived classes—rather than by calling a constructor.

Comment: I meant singleton **toolbox**, not singleton.

Comment: You provide not many information. And I don't have any idea what you want to ask.Toolbox has also some really good advantages, but "people said it's bad". This discussion is about nothing